# jQuery DataTables multi sort without shift

Tags: jquery, datatables

The awesome datatables plugin, (datatables.net) has the ability to do multi column sorting by holding in shift when clicking the header.

Is there a way to enable this without holding in the shift modifier? I'm completely at a loss :(

Comment: I was a hard task figuring out how to send multiple column sorts to the server. This question in itself answered my query.

Answer (score 2):

Odd request.  Of course it is there for a reason.  If you eliminate the requirement to hold down shift, how do you know if the user wants to sort by a second column all by itself, or wants to sort by two columns?  If a user clicks to sort on Column A, then clicks to sort on Column B - does the user want to sort by A and B or just B?

In any case, I don't see a way to do it within Datatables.  You can modify the source if you must have this feature.  If you download the non-minimized version, from here for example: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js, then search for `e.shiftKey`, you will see the code.  Instead of `if ( e.shiftKey )`, just make it `if(true)`, or comment out the if.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. (tested with datatables version 1.10.12)

You have to unbind the click event and recreate sorting function manually.

First, add a class to your datatable:

`<table class="datatableMultiSorting">`

Then add the JS :

```
$('.datatableMultiSorting th').unbind('click.DT');
$('.datatableMultiSorting th').click( function () {
    currentTable = $(this).closest(".datatableMultiSorting").dataTable();
    thisIndex = $(this).index();
    //console.log(thisIndex);
    var sortArray = [];
    $(this).siblings().andSelf().each(function(index) {
        if(index==thisIndex){
            if ($(this).hasClass("sorting")){
                sortArray.push([index,'asc']);
            }
            if ($(this).hasClass("sorting_asc")){
                sortArray.push([index,'desc']);
            }
        } else{
            if ($(this).hasClass("sorting_asc")){
                sortArray.push([index,'asc']);
            }
             if ($(this).hasClass("sorting_desc")){
                sortArray.push([index,'desc']);
            }
        }
    });
    currentTable.fnSort(sortArray);
});
```

**Note: use the script only after datatable initialisation.**